Dataflow Apache Beam DLP Integration Error: AttributeError during DLP Deidentification Process
I am trying to de identify(mask) the data using dataflow but when running the dataflow code getting weird error:
error:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 51, in loads
    return desired_pickle_lib.loads(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 422, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeidentifyFn' on <module 'apache_beam.runners.worker.sdk_worker_main' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py'>

code:
combined_script.py
import sys
import os
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions
import datetime
from google.cloud import dlp_v2, bigquery

class DeidentifyFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, project_id, deidentify_template):
        super(DeidentifyFn, self).__init__()
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.deidentify_template = deidentify_template

    def setup(self):
        self.dlp_client = dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient()
        self.bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=self.project_id)

    def deidentify_column(self, value):
        dlp_table = {
            "headers": [{"name": "value"}],
            "rows": [{"values": [{"string_value": str(value)}]}]
        }
        request = {
            "parent": f"projects/{self.project_id}/locations/us-east4",
            "deidentify_template_name": self.deidentify_template,
            "item": {"table": dlp_table}
        }
        response = self.dlp_client.deidentify_content(request=request)
        deidentified_value = response.item.table.rows[0].values[0].string_value
        return deidentified_value

    def process(self, row):
        for key, value in row.items():
            if key in ["Email", "PhoneNumber"] and value is not None:
                row[key] = self.deidentify_column(value)
            elif isinstance(value, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
                row[key] = value.isoformat()
        row['ingestion_date'] = datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()
        yield row

def run():
    # Pipeline Configuration Variables
    PROJECT_ID = 'project'
    DEIDENTIFY_TEMPLATE = 'projects/project/locations/us-east4/deidentifyTemplates/deidentifytemplateuseast4'
    INPUT_TABLE = 'project.dataset.pii_data_1million_partition'
    OUTPUT_TABLE = 'project.dataset.pii_data_1million_partition_deidentify'
    REGION = 'us-east4'

    options = PipelineOptions()
    gcp_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    gcp_options.project = PROJECT_ID
    gcp_options.region = REGION
    gcp_options.job_name = 'bq-dlp-deidentify'
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (
            p
            | 'ReadFromBigQuery' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query=f'SELECT * FROM `{INPUT_TABLE}` WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, DAY) = TIMESTAMP("2024-08-31")', use_standard_sql=True
            )
            | 'DeidentifyData' >> beam.ParDo(DeidentifyFn(PROJECT_ID, DEIDENTIFY_TEMPLATE))
            | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                OUTPUT_TABLE,
                schema='SCHEMA_AUTODETECT',
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://bucket/temp'
            )
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

Python version  - 3.11.6
apache-beam     -  2.55.0

Did you try to set save_main_session = True?https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#name-error

It changed the error:
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
SDK harness sdk-0-0 disconnected. This usually means that the process running the pipeline code has crashed. Inspect the Worker Logs and the Diagnostics tab to determine the cause of the crash.

You need to check the worker log (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#ViewDataflowLogs), which should contain more detailed errors.

dataflow template requires "conscrypt" library to run,  we can add in the conscrypt dependency. The default dataflow template by google excludes this library

Attribute error in worker log:
Could not load main session. Inspect which external dependencies are used in the main module of your pipeline. Verify that corresponding packages are installed in the pipeline runtime environment and their installed versions match the versions used in pipeline submission environment. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeidentifyFn' on <module 'apache_beam.runners.worker.sdk_worker_main' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py'>

Is this still the issue? You can try to move DeidentifyFn inside run().
